# Can an external application request a resize of a dashboard plugin?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Our external application would like to dynamically change the height of a dashboard plugin when the content inside changes.

For example, setting a plugin initial height of 200px while loading, and displaying 3 table rows @ 300px height, or 4 table rows @ 400px height once loaded.

Following the JH docs, an external application may install the bridge plugin to communicate with the Banno dashboard.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge

I'm able to use this plugin to `requestSync` and utilize other linking helper-methods.

However, when I try to request a resize, ie. `requestResize(800)`, the command is ignored by the Banno dashboard.

I'm able to see the post messages in the parent window but no changes occur to the height of the plugin itself.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that dynamically resizing a plugin is currently not supported and the height will always be the height specified in the [Plugin Configuration](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/).

The longer answer is that the [README for the Plugin Bridge](https://github.com/Banno/banno-plugin-framework-bridge) specifies that the *Host events* and *App events* are in an *alpha* phase of development. This means the alpha features are not verified to function across Banno's consumer apps.

- In contrast, the *Routing* feature of the Plugin Bridge *is* available to use and documented in the [jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/) page on JackHenry.Dev.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jaime, I did miss that it was in alpha. Looking forward to this feature!